# Spring Boot: Thymeleaf not resolving fragments after packaging

Tags: spring, fragment, spring-boot, thymeleaf

im using fragments like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fragment/nodeListWithStatus", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String nodeListWithStatus(Model model) {

    // status der nodes
    model.addAttribute("nodeList", nodeService.getNodeListWithOnlineStatus());

    return "/fragments :: nodeList";
}
```

The templates are in /src/main/resources/templates. This works fine when starting the application from IntelliJ. 
As soon as i create an .jar and start it, above code no longer works. Error:

```
[2014-10-21 20:37:09.191] log4j - 7941 ERROR [http-nio-666-exec-2] --- TemplateEngine: [THYMELEAF][http-nio-666-exec-2] Exception processing template "/fragments": Error resolving template "/fragments", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

When i open the .jar with winrar, i see /templates/fragments.html - so it seems to be there.

My pom.xml has this part for building the jar (Maven clean, install) :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>de.filth.Application</mainClass>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the leading `/` on the view name, i.e. you should return `fragments :: nodeList` rather than `/fragments :: nodeList`. Having made this change Thymeleaf should be able to find the template when run from your IDE or from a jar file.

If you're interested, here's what's happening under the hood:

The view name is used to search for a resource on the classpath. `fragments :: nodeList` means that the resource name is `/templates/fragments.html` and `/fragments :: nodeList` means that the resource name is `/templates//fragments.html` (note the double slash). When you're running in your IDE the resource is available straight off the filesystem and the double slash doesn't cause a problem. When you're running from a jar file the resource is nested within that jar and the double slash prevents it from being found. I don't fully understand why there's this difference in behaviour and it is rather unfortunate. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744) so that we (the Spring Boot team) can see if there's anything we can do to make the behaviour consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy for the explanation, it resolved my issue! Lets see if this can somehow be resolved deeper in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old topic, but I stumbled upon it while having problem with similar symptoms and different root cause. Wanted to share solution which helped me in case it could help somebody else...

Apparently name of the messages.properties file is case sensitive, but not everywhere. I had mine called "Messages.properties" (with capital M) and it worked just fine from inside IDE (IntelliJ), but once I tried to run app from jar, all messages were replaced with ??parameter.name??. Replacing M with lowercase m resolved the problem.